# Having Issue on Fetching Rows Using MySQLi Prepared Statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to get some data from the MySQL database by using the following Prepared Statement. but I am having two Problwms here:

1- the code ONLY returns the last row values but as you can see I am using the while iterator with `$stmt->fetch()` at

```
while($stmt->fetch());{
    echo  '<option value="'.$uid.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

2 - the other thing is when I try to use the `if($stmt->num_rows > 0){}` at code snippet 2 I am getting the **Cant' Find Data** message!

```
 <?php
     $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbmodel');
     if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     }
     $sql = 'SELECT uid, name  FROM `single-animals-tbl`';
     $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->execute();
     $stmt->bind_result($uid,$name);
 ?> 
 <select>
     <option value="0">Select From The List</option>  
     <?php 
         while($stmt->fetch());{
             echo  '<option value="'.$uid.'">'.$name.'</option>';
         }
         $stmt->close();
         $conn->close();
     ?> 
 </select>
```

snippet 2 with `if($stmt->num_rows > 0){}`

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'dbmodel');
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection Failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT uid, name  FROM `single-animals-tbl`';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($uid,$name);
    if($stmt->num_rows > 0){
    ?> 
        <select>
            <option value="0">Select From The List</option>  
            <?php 
                while($stmt->fetch());{
                    echo  '<option value="'.$uid.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                 }
                }else {
                     echo "Cant' Find Data";
                 }
                $stmt->close();
                $conn->close();
            ?> 
        </select>
```

Comment: if numrows says there's no rows, then your query returned no rows... have you tried running that query directly in a mysql shell? That or the query FAILED somehow, and since you're not checking for errors, you're just blindly assuming it succeeded.

Comment: @Marc B, thanks for comment, there are absolutly rows in the table plus as I said witdout using the if statement I am getting the last row

Comment: you have a `;` proceeding the `while` loop and also an additional, unnecessary, closing brace `}` preceeding the `else`

Comment: @scott, thanks for first part but I am not getting the unnecessary brace at else part!

Comment: The closing brace is necessary, it closes the block after the `if` statement.

Comment: Ah, it's the brace closing the `if` statement. Never mind.

Comment: So? what is the problem then?

Answer (score 1):

As for your first problem:
You are having a spurious semicolon after your while loop. So it is equivalent to

```
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    ;
}
{
    echo  '<option value="'.$uid.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
```

Remove that and it should work

Comment: Thnaks Mathias Becher, what a silly mistake! butt how about second part?

Comment: the first part yeah but for the second part no, however I find a solution by adding `$stmt->store_result();` before using the `if($stmt->num_rows > 0){}` but I couldn't figure it out how that related!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `get_result` instead of `bind_result` and proceed with `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead

P.S. this will need mysqlnd to be installed